# JWT web token encryption - SecurityAlgoritms.HmacSha256 vs SecurityAlgoritms.HmacSha256Signature

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, jwt

For token based authentication `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` provides a list of security algorithms that can be used to create `SigningCredentials`:

```
  string secretKey = "MySuperSecretKey";
  byte[] keybytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey);
  SecurityKey securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keybytes);
  SigningCredentials signingCredentials =
                    new SigningCredentials(securityKey,
                        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

  SigningCredentials signingCredentials =
                    new SigningCredentials(securityKey,
                        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
```

What is the difference between ***HmacSha256*** and ***HmacSha256Signature***? When would you use the signature one instead of the non-signature one?**

There are other "non signature" and "signature" algorithms as well. For example, RsaSha256 and RsaSha256Signature

Answer (score 14):

`HmacSha256` is a string constant evaluating to "HS256". `HmacSha256Signature` is also a string constant but evaluates to "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256"

The latest definition of `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms` does not include HmacSha256 but instead allows you to separate the signature and digest algorithms for the `SigningCredentials`.

You should use `HmacSha256Signature` for future-proofing your application as `HmacSha256` looks deprecated.

From the Microsoft docs...

> The members that have a Signature suffix can be used to specify the
>   signatureAlgoritm parameter and the members that have a Digest suffix
>   can be used to specify the digestAlgorithm parameter.

Comment: When using `HmacSha256Signature` instead of `HmacSha256` https://jwt.io/ fails to verify the signature for some reason.

Comment: Also, the RFC for JWT https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519 doesn't mention `http` notation.

Comment: @Konrad You still need to use `HmacSha256` to verify the algorithm type, as that is what is actually in the JWT