# My Web API keeps returning 401 Unauthorized despite the inclusion of jwt in the request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a web API that allows registration, login and retrieval of an entity, students data in this case. I added Jwt token based authentication that issues a Jwt on successful login. The problem is I keep getting 401 Unauthorized either or not I included the token in my request to the server. I saw a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784211/jwt-token-error-401-unauthorized-in-net-core-3-1)  but that doesn't work for me.

The Controller class

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/student")]
    
    public class StudentController:ControllerBase
    {
        IStudentRepository _student;
        IMapper _mapper;
        IConvertFileToByteArray _fileConverter;
        IAuthenticate _authenticate;
        public StudentController(IMapper mapper, IStudentRepository context,IConvertFileToByteArray converter,IAuthenticate authenticate)
        {
            _student = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _fileConverter = converter;
            _authenticate = authenticate;
        }
        [HttpGet("login")]
        [PasswordAttribute]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromQuery] LoginCredential credential)
        {
            Student student;
            try
            {
                
                student = await _student.GetStudentAsync(credential.Username);
                if (!_authenticate.AuthenticateUser(student.Password, credential.Password))
                {
                    return Unauthorized("Incorrect Username or Password");
                }
                var token=_authenticate.GenerateToken(credential.Username);
                return Ok(new { Token = token });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Unauthorized(e.Message);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("usrname",Name ="GetStudentUsingUsername")]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ReturnStudent>> Get([FromQuery]string Username)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetReq");
            Student student;
            IFormFile passport=null;
            try
            {
                student = await _student.GetStudentAsync(Username);
                Console.WriteLine(student.FirstName);
                if (student.ByteArrayofPassport.Length>1000)
                {
                    passport = new FormFile(new MemoryStream(student.ByteArrayofPassport), 0, student.ByteArrayofPassport.Length, "ByteArrayOfPassport", "passport");
                }
                ReturnStudent returnStudent = _mapper.Map<ReturnStudent>(student);
                returnStudent.Passport = passport;
                return Ok(returnStudent);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Ok(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Token is generated through the method

```
private readonly byte[] secret = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("REDACTED");
        public string GenerateToken(string username)
        {
            var tokenHandler=new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username) }),
                Expires =DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(secret), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            };
            var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
            return token;
        }
```

Service Configuration

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            /*services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "StudentManagementSystem2", Version = "v1" });
            });*/
            services.AddDbContext<StudentContext>();
            services.AddScoped<IStudentRepository,StudentRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IConvertFileToByteArray, ConvertFileToByteArray>();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthenticate, Authenticate>();
            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("REDACTED"))
                };
            });
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                    JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder =
                    defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

                options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                //app.UseSwagger();
                ///app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "StudentManagementSystem2 v1"));
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Which of the return statements for `Unauthorized` is being hit?

Comment: @TomW I think None of the return statements is getting a hit. I just receive a blank 401 Unauthorized response on postman. But it works if I remove the Authorize attribute on the Get method in the controller.

Comment: When you create the signing credentials in `GenerateToken`, you pass `SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256` and not `SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature` as per the example you linked to, is this difference intentional? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869902/jwt-web-token-encryption-securityalgoritms-hmacsha256-vs-securityalgoritms-hma) explains the difference but there seems to be some disagreement over what is required in practice which I can't completely follow.

Comment: @TomW Thanks for pointing that out. It doesn't resolve the issue when I changed the signature algorithm to ```HmacSha256Signature``` however.

Comment: I partially resolved the issu by setting both ```ValidateIssuer``` and ```ValidateAudience``` parameters to false. Its still not very clear why these two parameters have to be false. I tried reading the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters?view=azure-dotnet)  but it not very obvious. Can you offer any insight @TomW?

Comment: As you are generating your own token and not specifying its issuer or audience, this makes sense. Checking the token's issuer name is relevant when the signing key may be used to support issuing tokens for many tenants, for example `*.microsoft.com`. The audience represents which service or application the token is intended to grant access to. You have neither, but the defaults are appropriate for the usual use case of relying on a third-party identity provider which will provide these values in tokens that it issues.